# HTTPOnly Cookie isn't send with Ajax request

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, cookies, httpcookie

When my user logs in I set an HTTPonly cookie access_token. I have a middleware auth that verifies the value of the cookie access_token to authorize or not the user.
It works well when request are made directly from the server side and the cookies is successfully retrieved by the middleware.

But when I call some routes on my app (same domain and same port) via Ajax, the middleware doesn't find the cookie access_token (so refuses the connection) and on the Web inspector, I don't see any cookie send with the request.

It seems that Ajax request should send all copies (even HTTPonly cookies), but I don't know why it doesn't with my app.
Do you have any idea why ?

Thank you a lot !
Louie